# Phonegap Command filed with exit code 8 - Ubuntu

Tags: android, bash, cordova, ant

I'm trying to do my first android app in javascript with [phonegap][1] (cordova).
But when I put "phonegap run android" **it exits with error 8**, this is the code, here is the pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qofsZ.png (can't post screen because of reputation):

---

giulio@cucina:~/Documenti/web/sveglia/sveglia$ phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

/home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
**{ [Error: /home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }

   [error] /home/giulio/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8**

---

I've tried to follow these instructions: stackoverflow.com/questions/20323787/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-while-listing-android-targets/21142421#21142421 and stackoverflow.com/questions/24380283/phonegap-run-android-create-command-failed-with-exit-code-8-linux, but again it doesn't work.
This is the bashrc (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdLDY.png), I've put the code at the top:

---

export ANDROID_HOME="/media/giulio/Secondo\ Disco/Development/android-sdk-linux/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/media/giulio/Secondo\ Disco/Development/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share/ant/bin"
~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
...etc

---

I've already installed android packages, ant and everything necessary.
You're my last chance! D:

Comment: Have exported build-tools path?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried, It didn't work

Comment: Hi , When I run this command "cordova platform add android" in Ubuntu CLI, this Error I'm getting "Error: /home/sandeep/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.0.0/p‌​ackage/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8".Can you please Help me ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Export the two variables:

ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME

And, in addition, put android platform-tools on the PATH, works for me.

In my case, it was something like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/YOURUSER/sw/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/
export PATH="/home/YOURUSER/sw/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/:/home/YOURUSER/sw/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools:tools:$PATH"
```

Comment: Hi ruhanbidart, When I run this command "cordova platform add android" in Ubuntu,  this Error I'm getting   "Error: /home/sandeep/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.0.0/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8".Can you please Help me ASAP.